# Ловлю NullReferenceException не могу понять почему

Tags: c#

Есть у меня код, который ищет по id какой-то объект, правда вылетает NullReferenceException.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int id;
        Objects[] objects = new Objects[2];

        objects[0].Title = "Bed";
        objects[0].Id = 30;

        objects[1].Title = "Laptop";
        objects[1].Id = 55;

        id = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
        {
            if (id == objects[i].Id)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I found this item!");
                Console.WriteLine("It's {0}", objects[i].Title);
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }
}

class Objects
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

[image: NullReferenceException]

Comment: Так-то в ошибке четко написана проблема и даже указывается строка, где ошибка вылетает. А проблема в том, что хоть вы и создали массив объектов, но он пуст. Ну и на будущее: для собственных классов лучше придумывать такие названия, которые будут показывать его предназначение. Например, Product, что сразу даст понять о том, что там может находится.

Comment: Просто запомните, что массив заполняется значениями по умолчанию. `default(T)`. Для классов это `null`, у типов же значения (структур) - значение, у которого все поля проинициализированы по умолчанию

Answer (score 1):

```
Objects[] objects = new Objects[2];

objects[0] = new Objects();
objects[0].Title = "Bed";
objects[0].Id = 30;

objects[1] = new Objects();
objects[1].Title = "Laptop";
objects[1].Id = 55;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Objects[] objects = new[]
{
   new Objects
   {
      Title = "Bed",
      Id = 30
   },
   new Objects
   {
      Title = "Laptop",
      Id = 55
   }
}
```